# Using Dreamweaver with JSP/JSTL (Scriptlet vs JSTL)

Tags: jsp, jstl, dreamweaver

I am considering whether using JSTL is better than Scriptlets on a JSP page and one consideration is the tool that the web designers will be using to generate the JSP pages. Since Dreamweaver seems to be the industry standard product, I am using that as a reference point.

I can't find any up-to-date information about Dreamweaver support for JSP, specifically JSTL. Does the latest version support JSTL inherently? For example, can a web designer build a page and put a `c:foreach` tag in it to indicate that there is looping?

Comment: JSTL is absolutely better. Scriptlets == Evil. I don't have a direct answer as I don't use Dreamweaver for JSP (I just code it plain using Eclipse; visual editors are namely Evil as well), but I see that Google has lot of answers/hints: http://www.google.com/search?q=dreamweaver+jsp Have you already checked it? Install Google on your machine as well. It will be your best friend.

Comment: @BalusC - Google does not have any pages or and message board posts past 2004 about using JSTL in Dreamweaver.. Though I'm glad you answered my question even though you have no experience with the topic at hand.

Comment: No problem. Google however reveals that you would need JSFToolbox for this. I also just tried it at my CS3 (version 8.0) and only JSP 2.0 tags are supported. No JSTL or consorts. If the question remains unanswered for a long time (I have never met one yet who develops JSP in Dreamweaver), then you may try to repost the question at superuser.com, this question is namely more targeted on an software product than on programming.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver CS3 was the last version that included JSP support. Here's an announcement from around the time of the CS3 launch that list the i\features that were to be deprecated:
[Deprecated features in Dreamweaver](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402489.html)

I'm not sure about how much the JSFToolbow can help with "bringing back" the JSP support.